# (Programatically) infer required AWS IAM permissions required to deploy an AWS template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm working on an automated pipeline (using Jenkins) that deploys AWS Cloudformation Templates residing in a git repository to AWS.

I have a working pipeline that works off of an AWS IAM user whose access keys are used by a Jenkins job to talk to the AWS Cloudformation API.

The issue I'm facing is that preferably I would have this IAM user to have as little permission as possible, but it should have enough permissions both to access the Cloudformation API but also to create the resources I have templates for.

In order to determine this minimal permission set, my question is whether there exists an application, package or AWS utility (I haven't been able to find one yet) to infer the IAM permissions required to execute a given (set of) Cloudformation templates, that can preferably be used programatically.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

This is something that would be very nice to have, but for some reason Amazon is not willing to provide an API to check for this.

One hacky way to approach this could be to run the cloudformation template over and over again and check the output for the missing permissions. Then you add them each time to a temporary IAM role and repeat until you have all the permissions to launch your template. This might take a rather long time, but could be the only actual way to programmatically approach this.